# C# WinForms event FormClosing not slove Cannot access a disposed object exception

Tags: c#, winforms

In my project where i programmatically create new form and show it as dialog all time i get exception:

> System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed object.'

I try with **ClosingEvent** but that not work in my project.

**Here is my code:**

```
private void productNameTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
        using (Form productDialog = new Form())
        {
            productDialog.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(productDialog_FormClosing);

            productDialog.ShowDialog();
        }
}


  private void productDialog_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {

        productDialog.Hide();
        productDialog.Parent = null;

        MessageBox.Show("Triggered");     // Showed on close

        e.Cancel = true; //hides the form, cancels closing event

    }
```

When i close opened dialog on "**X**" and try again to open it i get exception. Whay **e.Cancel** not working but message box is showed. 
What i do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have written `using (Form productDialog = new Form())` so productDialog Form will be disposed as soon as your `productNameTextBox_KeyDown` will finish its part. You can read about this here [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement)